# IIS 7. Websites routing to avoid CORS

Tags: iis-7, cors, asp.net-web-api, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup my local development environment for an angular application. I have the following projects:

1. .NET Web API project that is hosted on a separate website (let's say localhost:81)
2. MVC project with angular components hosted on default web site (localhost)

I want to use API from my angular app, however right now I need to deal with CORS requests as API is hosted on different web site. I want to avoid it.

I want to setup and endpoint for my MVC site (localhost/api) that is the proxy to API web site.

How can I do this using IIS?

URL rewrite module is not suited for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question or points you in the right direction, I am also looking into this,

I used POSTMAN to test IIS web site to return something, for example

```
http://localhost/assets/json/config.json?=undefined
```

...I get the following header items:
[Postman GET API result without CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFLW.png)

as you can see the CORS is missing,

1. In the root directory which IIS web site points at (i.e. wwwroot) create if one does not exist yet

   ```
   web.config
   ```

   file and in it add the following

[Adding web.config file to IIS web app root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OLom.png)

[web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqCc7.png)

2. now run same thing with postman again and you should see CORS appearing

[Postman GET API result with CORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x1fp.png)

source:
https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html